# Como arredondar posição no Unity

Tags: unity-5

Meu objeto se move pelas teclas A,D,W,S. Ele se move de 1 em 1. Entretanto, essa posição nem sempre é redonda, podendo variar de 1.5 a 1.900 e isso atrapalha na colisão. Existe algum comando para arredondar posições?

Comment: Sim, existe o [`Mathf.Round`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Round.html). Não respondi porque não sei se isso resolve o seu problema, pois a pergunta não está totalmente clara (o que é uma "posição"? é um valor de um `Vector3` que vc usa para fazer a translação? Por que isso atrapalha a colisão? A colisão é manualmente feita por vc, ou é a Unity que está fazendo? etc).